# How to access elements of a dynamic array of string arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm trying to use opencsv (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).  There are examples included with the download of opencsv.  Here's an excerpt of their example for creating a dynamic array:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Name: [" + nextLine[0] + "]\nAddress: [" + nextLine[1] + "]\nEmail: [" + nextLine[2] + "]");
}
```

The CSV file it reads is as follows:

```
Joe Demo,"2 Demo Street, Demoville, Australia. 2615",joe@someaddress.com
Jim Sample,"3 Sample Street, Sampleville, Australia. 2615",jim@sample.com
Jack Example,"1 Example Street, Exampleville, Australia. 2615",jack@example.com
```

If I move the println statement outside of the while loop, I get an error in Eclipse: "Null pointer access: the variable nextLine can only be null at this location."

My guess is that nextLine has a pointer currently pointing to it's last position or past its last position.  I think my question is, how do I control that pointer?

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding the error here. Since the condition of your loop is to continue until `nextLine == null`, you're guaranteed afterwards that it will be `null`, which is why Eclipse is complaining. You must use the variable within the loop or change your condition.

Answer (score 2):

You exit the loop, when `nextLine == null`. Therefore, when you move your `println` statement out of the loop, `nextLine` is `null`. The error `"Null pointer access: the variable nextLine can only be null at this location."` makes total sense.

To access everything you read after the loop you could do the following:

Add this before you enter the loop:

```
List<String[]> readLines = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in the loop do this:

```
readLines.add(nextLine);
```

So after the loop you can read all of your read lines out of the `readLines` list.

Comment: Oh!  So the code as written discards all the read lines, correct?  It just keeps overwriting the same array with each iteration, then for the last iteration it writes null to that array?  Thanks so much!

Comment: you create a new array for each read line, but lose (overwrite) the reference to it in the next iteration. So your read lines may still be in memory, but they are eligible for garbage collection and you cannot access them anymore. After the last loop iteration in your code your reference will point to `null`, and you can't access any lines any more.